# Correctly Implement Virtual Function from Inherited Templated Class

Tags: c++

I'm a little confused over here! Let's say I have an interface

```
template <typename T>
class JsonSerializable {

public:

    virtual json AsJson() const;

    virtual T FromJson(json in) const;

};
```

How do I correctly use this interface in a class or struct like:

```
struct X : public JsonSerializable<X>
{
    float a;
    float b;

    virtual json AsJson() const override
    {
      return json();
    }

    RankingInfoTerm FromJson(json in)
    {
        RankingInfoTerm out;
        return out;
    }

};
```

Right now I'm just getting a bunch of linker errors no matter what I seem to try. I suspect I'm missing something extremely obvious. Any help and explanation is appreciated!

Comment: First of all your `JsonSerializable` class misses its template parameters. Please check for the proper syntax.

Comment: You syntax is severely screwed. Post a [mcve] reproducing the linker errors please.

Comment: please show real code and inlucde the error message. Strictly speaking there is no way to use `JsonSerializable` correctly, because already the first part of your code does not compile

Comment: Are you looking for something like `template <typename T> class JsonSerializable { ... };` plus `struct X : public JsonSerializable<RankingInfoTerm> { ... };` ?

Comment: Pretty sure `fromJson` should not be const and not return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't include any correct code that we can try and you didn't show what kind of error message is bothering you in particular, but here is the example on how to override methods from template interfaces:

```
template <class T>
class JsonSerializable {
public:
    virtual ~JsonSerializable() = default;
    virtual T fromJson(/* inpur args here */) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class X: public JsonSerializable<T> {
public:
    ~X() override = default;
    T fromJson(/* inpur args here */) override {
        // put here some real impl
        return T();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<JsonSerializable<float> > ptr2Base;
    ptr2Base.reset(new X<float>);  // template arguments of X and SerializableJson must be the same
    std::cout << ptr2Base->fromJson() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In `fromJson` signature I didn't use any input arguments just to compile the example. Later of course you might want to write the real implementation:

```
T fromJson(const SomeKindOfJson& json) {
    // convert json to type T and return it
}
```

Comment: I'd assume `fromJson` should rather look like this: `void fromJson(Something const& json { /* set own members according to json object */ }`...

Comment: Well, yes, I would do it like this, then maybe the Interface does not even need to be a template. But OP asked about `T fromJson(json)`, unfortunately not very clearly.

Comment: Suppose that's rather due to some misunderstanding. Assuming I want to create a new X: `X tmp; X final = tmp.fromJson(...);`, so I'm forced to create a temporary (unless I already have some other instance I can *abuse* for). I think OP is after something like `static virtual T fromJson(...) = 0`, which does not exist in C++, though...

Answer (score 2):

Now let's assume you want to create a totally new object from json. With signature as provided, it would necessarily look similar to the following:

```
X instance;
X instance = tmp.fromJson(data);
```

So you need to create an object first, on which you then *can* call `fromJson` on, just to overwrite it with the one created from within `fromJson` – or you create temporary that is discarded afterwards again.

OK, if you already have another object, you could *abuse* it for constructing a totally unrelated one. Not really a good design...

What you'd rather want is code like:

```
X instance;
instance.fromJson(data);
```

You won't create unnecessary temporaries this way, but you'd need to adjust your function appropriately:

```
virtual void fromJson(JSON const& json);
//       ^                             ^ non-const!
```

You might be looking for a possibility to write:

```
X instance = X::fromJson(data);
```

Problem: You'd need a static function for, but such one *cannot* be virtual. A solution then, though, might look like this:

```
template <typename T>
class JsonSerializable
{
public:
    virtual json asJson() const;

    static T fromJson(json in)
    {
        T t;
        t.readJson(in);
        return t;
    }

private:
    virtual void readJson(json in) = 0;
};
```

where the then static and non-virtual function would call another private *but* virtual function.

Comment: 'final' is a c++11 keyword. You can not use it as an identifier.

Comment: @Red.Wave Right – wanted to emphasize the difference to temporary, without paying attention (have I been drunk at that time???).

Comment: check local time. Was it like 3am or so?